# Changing og:url dynamically with php

Tags: php, facebook

Can I change meta tags dynamically

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.someurl.com/948116"/>
```

so that when I go to test on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ it shows the change there? I already tried with JavaScript but sharing debugger shows static data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
<?php 
$url = "http://your_url";
echo "<meta property='og:url' content='$url'/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not parse JavaScript, it is not possible to use dynamic OG Tags.